# NoSQL search for cascading/looping results?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Apologies if the title is not all that clear, I am just starting with NoSQL and I don't know all the terminology as of yet.

I have a database, DBA, with a collection of Products. These products can be Raw or Intermediates, and they can join together to make more Intermediates. For example, Raw_1 can be part of Intermediate_1, which in turn can be part of Intermediate_2.

My data structure is as follows:

```
_id
    64b66ab38e74a50fd5a2089a
Id
    10
Code
    "FU001"
Type
    "Intermediate"
Belongs_to
    "ZW001"
```

What I would like is to be able to search for the final product, say "Intermediate_2", and have returned both Intermediate_1 AND Raw_1. Is that possible?

Thanks!

I've tried searching in the MongoDB documentation but I haven't found anything related to it, and was wondering if there could be some technique or practice to help me achieve the expected result.

Comment: In order to make such queries, you can you some aggregation functions (cf : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#mongodb-method-db.collection.aggregate)
To make a recursive search you can use the $graphLookup operator :
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

If you want better help, please provide full example of data you have and the expected result.